# How to keep append any element while reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to know how I could keep an element that I have appended in jQuery alive ?
I have a form, when the value of a  is changing, an element append.
But when there are errors it reload the page and print the errors.
But the element appended disappear after reloading the page of course..

```
<form method="post" action="?action=comment">
    <select id="tag" name="tag">
        <option value="1">super</option>
        <option value="2">super</option>
    </select>
    <span id="elem_added"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

<script>
    $("#tag").change(function(e){
        option = $(this).val();

        if (option == "1")
        {
             $("#elem_added").append("<input type='text' name='test' id='input_added' />");
        }
    });
</script>
```

So any Idea to keep it in my page ?

Thx everyone !

ps: I don't use ajax and I won't

Comment: you can't. you have to store a flag that says the element was added, then check said flag and re-add the element (serverside or clientside, doesn't matter). Ajax would be ideal for this kind of work so that you don't have to re-add the element or store anything.

Comment: Depending on how you are reloading the page, you could append some information to the end of the url and have the page read that to re-generate the added content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol by design and you need state.

To solve this problem [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) ere introduced.

Store it before you reload the page, and read it, if it's there, add the text.

Assuming [the `docCookies` shim from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Before navigating away

```
docCookies.setItem("wasloaded","true");
```

After refresh:

```
if(docCookies.getItem("wasloaded")){
     //add text
};
```

In your case, this would be something like:

```
    if (option == "1" || docCookies.getItem("wasloaded")){
        $("#elem_added").append("<input type='text' name='test' id='input_added' />");
        docCookies.setItem("wasloaded",true);
    }
```

I agree with Kevin by the way, AJAX would be ideal for this sort of thing.

A more modern approach would be to use [`document.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#localStorage) to maintain state.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what the element will be who not keep it hidden markup and just show it based on your conditions. And on reload simply check your conditions again. IMHO is the best approach.

If you still want to append it you need to store information that you've append the element (or html on a form) in localstorage or cookie.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't wanna use ajax you can use cookies http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

store you data in a cookie and reappend it at loading